# ios printing from computer connected via WIFI

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, macos, airprint

Is it possible to print from an ios device to a printer which is connected to a mac. The mac and ios device are both on the same wireless network.

If there isn't an official way of doing this, the I am guessing I am going to have to write a Mac app which the ios app connects to, sends the data and then the mac app prints. For this, does anyone have rough guidelines as how I should do this? The main problem here for me is to send the data to mac over wifi.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the mac owner to get AirPrint to work on their printer.  I think it's possible to print to any mac-printable printer via AirPrint, although it may require a little work from the user.  I had no problem getting this to work for my printer, which  is not one of the few AirPrint-friendly ones.

Once that is set up, AirPrint works without any extra code from the iOS app.  In other words, it is best practice to use the suggested AirPrint API, doing nothing special to try to support particular printers.  To build in custom support for wifi printing from your app would be a huge load of work, and abstracting away this work is exactly the goal of device drivers.  Motivated users can get this working today, and I am hoping Apple will continue to build in more support for AirPrint with future OS updates.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the kind of questions Stack Overflow is made for.  Try posting this kind of questions on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) instead.

But, to give you a short answer: [Airprint Activator](http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/)

EDIT: There is not really an official way to do this yourself.  Airprint relies on many things ([CUPS](http://www.cups.org/), an Apple proprieteray URF to PDF conversion filter, Bonjour, etc.) that aren't necessary easy to implement, especially since these specifications are relatively obscure and not well publicly documented.

Comment: How is it not the kind of question SO is made for? I am asking if there's a class/way in Cocoa-Touch API that will allow me to print? And if not, how to integrate a small server into a Mac app..

Comment: Ha ok, sorry about that, I mainly understood your original question as "How to do it, is there a software to do it".